# Is it possible to have multiple database connections for ExpressionEngine?

Tags: database

When setting up the database settings of a project I know that there is the default active group "expressionengine" found in the database.php file and you can add more than one group, I was just wondering if there is a way that I could load at most 2 database connections at the same time.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? In what ways would the second database connection be used? Would you expect ExpressionEngine to use the second connection for something, or would you use it in a custom add-on?

Comment: Yes, it would be used for a custom add-on for my site. It would be just for reading the data from the other database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it took too long, if anyone wanted to do this and have multiple connections just follow these steps like I did: http://tutsnare.com/connecting-multiple-database-in-codeigniter/. hope it helps